# JMenuBar arrow keys work the opposite of what expected because componentOrientation is set to Right to Left

Tags: java, swing, jmenubar

After applying `setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT)` to the JMenuBar the arrow keys started to behave the opposite of what expected. Right arrow goes left and Left arrow goes right when trying to traverse through keyboard.

By the way, I'm using Java `11.0.12` on Windows 10.

Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.ComponentOrientation;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MenuBarProblem extends JFrame {
        
    private JMenuBar menuBar;
    
    private JMenu firstMenu;
    private JMenuItem a;
    private JMenuItem b;
    
    private JMenu secondMenu;
    private JMenuItem c;
    private JMenuItem d;
    
    private JMenu thirdMenu;
    private JMenuItem e;
    private JMenuItem f;
    
    public MenuBarProblem() {
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        this.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        this.setSize(screenSize);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        this.firstMenu = new JMenu("first");
        this.a = new JMenuItem("a");
        this.b = new JMenuItem("b");
        this.firstMenu.add(this.a);
        this.firstMenu.add(this.b);
        
        this.secondMenu = new JMenu("second");
        this.c = new JMenuItem("c");
        this.d = new JMenuItem("d");
        this.secondMenu.add(this.c);
        this.secondMenu.add(this.d);
        
        this.thirdMenu = new JMenu("third");
        this.e = new JMenuItem("e");
        this.f = new JMenuItem("f");
        this.thirdMenu.add(this.e);
        this.thirdMenu.add(this.f);
        
        this.menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        this.menuBar.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT); //Here is the reason
        this.menuBar.add(this.firstMenu);
        this.menuBar.add(this.secondMenu);
        this.menuBar.add(this.thirdMenu);
        this.setJMenuBar(this.menuBar);
    }

}
```

Here is also the main class which contains the main method:

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException
                            | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (InvocationTargetException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MenuBarProblem test = new MenuBarProblem();
                test.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Update: The issue turned out to be a bug and now it's been added to the bug database [here](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8277369).

Comment: This looks like a bug to me. As a workaround I replaced **this.menuBar.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);** by **this.menuBar.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());** and then it worked.

Comment: Now alt key doesn't set selection on the jmenubar. @tniessen

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile the problem has been accepted as a bug (see above) and so the suggested solution is a temporary patch, build upon the internal implementation of the WindowsLookAndFeel.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.ComponentOrientation;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.KeyEventDispatcher;
import java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.MenuElement;
import javax.swing.MenuSelectionManager;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MenuBarProblem extends JFrame {

    private JMenuBar menuBar;

    private JMenu firstMenu;
    private JMenuItem a;
    private JMenuItem b;

    private JMenu secondMenu;
    private JMenuItem c;
    private JMenuItem d;

    private JMenu thirdMenu;
    private JMenuItem e;
    private JMenuItem f;

    private JMenu fourthMenu;
    private JMenuItem g;
    private JMenuItem h;

    private KeyboardFocusManager keyboardFocusManager;

    public MenuBarProblem() {

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 200));
        add(panel);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        firstMenu = new JMenu("first");
        a = new JMenuItem("a");
        b = new JMenuItem("b");
        firstMenu.add(a);
        firstMenu.add(b);

        secondMenu = new JMenu("second");
        c = new JMenuItem("c");
        d = new JMenuItem("d");
        secondMenu.add(c);
        secondMenu.add(d);

        thirdMenu = new JMenu("third");
        e = new JMenuItem("e");
        f = new JMenuItem("f");
        thirdMenu.add(e);
        thirdMenu.add(f);

        fourthMenu = new JMenu("fourth");
        g = new JMenuItem("g");
        h = new JMenuItem("h");
        fourthMenu.add(g);
        fourthMenu.add(h);

        menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        menuBar.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT); // Here is the reason
        menuBar.add(firstMenu);
        menuBar.add(secondMenu);
        menuBar.add(thirdMenu);
        menuBar.add(fourthMenu);

        setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        pack();

        keyboardFocusManager = KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager();
        keyboardFocusManager.addKeyEventDispatcher(new MSMKeyEventDispatcher());
    }

    private class MSMKeyEventDispatcher implements KeyEventDispatcher {

        int index = -1;

        private void select(int index) {
            JMenu menu = menuBar.getMenu(index);
            if (menu != null) {
                MenuSelectionManager msm = MenuSelectionManager.defaultManager();
                MenuElement path[] = new MenuElement[2];
                path[0] = menuBar;
                path[1] = menu;
                msm.setSelectedPath(path);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
            if (MenuBarProblem.this.getFocusOwner() == null) {
                return false;
            }
            if (e.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED) {
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ALT) {
                    MenuSelectionManager msm = MenuSelectionManager.defaultManager();
                    if (msm.getSelectedPath().length == 0) {
                        index = 0;
                        select(index);
                    } else {
                        msm.setSelectedPath(null);
                        index = -1;
                    }
                    return true;
                } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
                    if (index >= 0) {
                        --index;
                        if (index < 0) {
                            index = menuBar.getComponentCount() - 1;
                        }
                        select(index);
                        return true;
                    }
                } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
                    if (index >= 0) {
                        ++index;
                        if (index >= menuBar.getComponentCount()) {
                            index = 0;
                        }
                        select(index);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Addendum: The most simple idea for a solution is probably a KeyEventDispatcher switching the KeyCodes KeyEvent.VK_LEFT and KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT of the received KeyEvent and redispatching the changed KeyEvent. However, it turned out that this has absolutely no effect.

Comment: Thank you @tniessen I really appreciate your effort. There are still 3 problems. The first is when typing alt again the focus doesn't get removed. The second is while a menu is opened and I press an arrow key the other menus doesn't get opened automatically. The third is once I press alt the arrow keys still work even if the focus is removed.

Comment: @Bu Saeed: Thanks for your reply. I use neither the WindowsLookAndFeel nor any keys for the menu. So, your three problems feel like three new requirements to me (as pressing the Alt key in your first comment). I have changed the coded slightly in order to satisfy the first and the third issue. According to my experience adding a KeyEventDispatcher requires utmost care with respect to implementation, maintenance and tests. Please try to understand the current implementation, because most likely you have to adapt it again, e.g. when you try to apply it to another situation.

Comment: @Bu Saeed: The second issue needs more changes. When a menu is opened, the root pane has the focus and by MenuSelectionManager#getSelectedPath one can determine whether a menu is opened and which one. And then one can open the menu to the left or right, resp., by means of  MenuSelectionManager#setSelectedPath, but this time the path has to have three elements, the third one being path[2] = (MenuElement) menu.getPopupMenu(). Maybe you like to try this. I am busy this week, but will return to check.